# Dynamic Slicer Percentage Increase

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a dataset in Power BI.

This dataset has data on:

1. Employee Name (Column)
2. Employee Seniority (Column)
3. Employee Current Salary (Column)
4. Employee Salary Increase Minimum Proposal % (Measure)
5. Employee Salary Increase Maximum Proposal % (Measure)

To give you context (fictitious use case)
I want to give my employees a salary increase based on the data.

I have already determined with measures what percentage this increase should be (based on the current salary).

I want to create a new measure called: Future Salary.

I would like to create a slicer where the minimum is 'Employee Salary Increase Minimum Proposal %' and the maximum is 'Employee Salary Increase Maximum Proposal %'. This slicer must determine the increase and 'future salary' must display this.

So suppose:
Employee 'John'.
Salary 2023 - $50,000
Employee Salary Increase Minimum Proposal % - 4%
Employee Salary Increase Maximum Proposal % - 10%

I want you to have a slicer between 4%-10% and you can slide the slicer to determine how much increase you want indicates the current salary. So with a 4% increase you should see 'Future Salary' at $52,000.

Do you know the easiest way to achieve this in Power BI?

Comment: How do you envision this working? A slicer (with different scale depending on the min/max) for each employee? Not possible to have a slicer per employee. If you are thinking of having a drill-through to a page for one single employee - then this is possible. If the former, then PowerApp might be a better tool to use.